# Pydantic: Make field None in validator based on other field's value

Tags: python, pydantic

I'm using the pydantic `BaseModel` with a validator like this:

```
from datetime import date
from typing import List, Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, BaseConfig, validator

class Model(BaseModel):
    class Config(BaseConfig):
        allow_population_by_alias = True
        fields = {
            "some_date": {
                "alias": "some_list"
            }
        }
    some_date: Optional[date]
    some_list: List[date]

    @validator("some_date", pre=True, always=True)
    def validate_date(cls, value):
        if len(value) < 2: # here value is some_list
            return None
        return value[0] # return the first value - let's assume it's a date string

# This reproduces the problem
m = Model(some_list=['2019-01-03'])
```

I would like to compute the value of `some_date` based on the value of `some_list` and make it `None` if a certain condition met.

My JSON never contains the field `some_date`, it's always populated based on `some_list` hence `pre=True, always=True`. However the default validator for `some_date` will run *after* my custom one, which will fail if `validate_date` returns `None`.

Is there a way to create such a field which is only computed by another one and still can be `Optional`?

Comment: @normanius my bad, forgot that `allow...` and `fields` were in an inner Config class

Comment: btw I'm trying with python 3.6.1 and pydantic 0.16.1

Comment: Newer versions of pydantic (starting with 0.20) handle your use case much better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**: As others pointed out, this can be done now with newer versions (>=0.20). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65128634/3388962). (Side note: even the OP's code works now, but doing it without alias is even better.)

---

<strike>From skim reading documentation and source of pydantic, I tend to to say that pydantic's validation mechanism currently has very limited support for type-transformations (`list -> date`, `list -> NoneType`) within the validation functions.</strike>

Taking a step back, however, your approach using an `alias` and the flag `allow_population_by_alias` seems a bit overloaded. `some_date` is needed only as a shortcut for `some_list[0] if len(some_list) >= 2 else None`, but it's never set independently from `some_list`. If that's really the case, why not opting for the following option?

```
class Model(BaseModel):
    some_list: List[date] = ...

    @property 
    def some_date(self):
        return None if len(self.some_list) < 2 else self.some_list[0]
```

Comment: I was wondering if my approach was possible at all, but you are right, this problem shouldn’t be solved like this

Comment: what's wrong with doing it this way? seems simple. why is validator better approach?

Answer (score 61):

If you want to be able to dynamically modify a field according to another one, you can use the `values` argument. It holds all the previous fields, and careful: the **order matters**. You could do this either using a `validator` or a `root_validator`.

### With a `validator`

```py
>>> from datetime import date
>>> from typing import List, Optional
>>> from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
>>> class Model(BaseModel):
        some_list: List[date]
        some_date: Optional[date]
    
        @validator("some_date", always=True)
        def validate_date(cls, value, values):
            if len(values["some_list"]) < 2:
                return None
            return values["some_list"][0]

>>> Model(some_list=['2019-01-03', '2020-01-03', '2021-01-03'])
Model(some_list=[datetime.date(2019, 1, 3), datetime.date(2020, 1, 3), datetime.date(2021, 1, 3)],
      some_date=datetime.date(2019, 1, 3))
```

But as I said if you exchange the order of `some_list` and `some_date`, you will have a `KeyError: 'some_list'`!

### With a `root_validator`

Another option would be to use a `root_validator`. These act on all fields:

```py
>>> class Model(BaseModel):
        some_list: List[date]
        some_date: Optional[date]
    
        @root_validator
        def validate_date(cls, values):
            if not len(values["some_list"]) < 2:
                values["some_date"] = values["some_list"][0]
            return values

>>> Model(some_list=['2019-01-03', '2020-01-03', '2021-01-03'])
Model(some_list=[datetime.date(2019, 1, 3), datetime.date(2020, 1, 3), datetime.date(2021, 1, 3)],
      some_date=datetime.date(2019, 1, 3))
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, imho: "the **order** [of declared attributes] **matters**" - ran into this exact sneaky `KeyError`

Comment: does not work if you set `exclude=True` on `some_list` :(

Comment: @RamonDias which seems logical no? You would need to adapt the validator to handle this case, otherwise `some_list` is not present.

Comment: @tupui I thought `exclude=True` would only count for dumping.

Comment: If you want to populate a filed based on another one then make sure you use `always=True` as in the provided answer. Otherwise if the field you want to populate is null it will not work.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use `values` according to [pydantic docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/)

> you can also add any subset of the following arguments to the
>   signature (the names must match):
>
> values: a dict containing the
>   name-to-value mapping of any previously-validated fields
>
> config: the
>   model config
>
> field: the field being validated
>
> **kwargs: if provided, this will include the arguments above not explicitly listed in the signature

```py
@validator()
def set_value_to_zero(cls, v, values):
    # look up other value in values, set v accordingly.
```

Answer (score 1):

What about overriding the `__init__`?

```
from datetime import date
from typing import List, Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Model(BaseModel):
    some_date: Optional[date]
    some_list: List[date]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # Modify the arguments
        if len(kwargs['some_list']) < 2:
            kwargs['some_date'] = None
        else:
            kwargs['some_date'] = kwargs['some_list'][0]

        # Call parent's __init__
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

Model(some_list=['2019-01-03', '2022-01-01'])
# Output: Model(some_date=datetime.date(2019, 1, 3), some_list=[datetime.date(2019, 1, 3), datetime.date(2022, 1, 1)])
```

Note that if you modify the instance after creation, this validation is not executed.